# Typo3 Powermail - Customize Javascript

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, extbase, powermail

How to customize the Powermail javascript without the risk to overwrite it with the next update? To be specific: I would like to change the ajax function of Powermail Version 3.6.0.

Is there a possibility to move the javascript into my template extension like it is possible with typoscript?

```
plugin.tx_powermail.view.templateRootPaths.10 = ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on which typoscript setup are you including from the powermail extension. For the standard one should be something like: `page.includeJSFooter.powermailForm`

You can find non-minified versions of javascript you want to override in Resources/Private/JavaScripts folder.